# Acessar state do React Native Scrollable Tab View

Tags: react-native

Tenho uma aplicação React Native com a biblioteca react-native-scrollable-tab-view, onde essa tab view contém 3 nós-filhos:

**App.js**

```
<ScrollableTabView
          style={{marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: '#1C4747', }}
          tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
          tabBarActiveTextColor={"#fff"}
          tabBarInactiveTextColor={"#ccc"}
          initialPage={0}
          renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar />}
        >
          <RotaEntrega tabLabel='ROTA' />
          <ChildOne tabLabel='ORDENS' text='ORDENS' size={17} weight="500" />
          <ChildTwo tabLabel='HISTÓRICO' text='HISTÓRICO' size={17} weight="500" />

</ScrollableTabView>
```

Em RotaEntrega.js há uma requisição HTTP que retorna um json do servidor. Porém, me dei conta que essa mesma requisição é usada nos outros dois nós (ChildOne e ChildTwo), então eu teria que migrar a requisição para o App.js e usar o resultado nos tabs do ScrollableTabView. Posso passar esses dados usando `props`, mas os tabs filhos teriam que modificar o state em App.js...

Em resumo:

App.js faz requisição HTTP e obtém JSON.
Salva JSON no state.
Passa o state para os tabs RotaEntrega, ChildOne, ChildTwo.
Os tabs lêem e modificam o state de App.js.

Atualmente a requisição está RotaEntrega.js:

```
_route = async(codDriver) => {
    const apiCall = await fetch(`http://urlaqui.com.br/testes/api.php?driver=${codDriver}`);
    const response = await apiCall.json();

    let latLongObj = {
      latitude: parseFloat(response.os[0].address.latitude),
      longitude: parseFloat(response.os[0].address.longitude)
    };

    this.setState({
      route: response.success ? [ response.os[0] ] : [], //only first route in the list
      routeFound: response.success,
      orders: response.success ? response.os : [], //and put the all orders to this array
      destination: latLongObj
    });
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this._route("51ds515");
  }
```

Logo o código acima passará para App.js.

Como posso implementar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Uma resolução seria trabalhar com funções vinculadas ao Objeto Instanciado( O Detentor do Estado do App.js: Bind ou Arrow Functions ).
Você implementa funções em AppJS que alterem o estado do nó pai e passa
essas funções para os nós filhos.

Exemplo:

**App.js**

```
 //...
 class App exetends React.Component {

   _request(){ // ... }

   updateState = (args) => {if(args){this.setState(args);}}

   render(){
     return (
       <ScrollableTabView
         style={{marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: '#1C4747', }}
         tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
         tabBarActiveTextColor={"#fff"}
         tabBarInactiveTextColor={"#ccc"}
         initialPage={0}
         renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar />}
       >
         <RotaEntrega tabLabel='ROTA' updateState={this.updateState} />
         <ChildOne tabLabel='ORDENS' text='ORDENS' size={17} weight="500"  updateState={this.updateState}/>
         <ChildTwo tabLabel='HISTÓRICO' text='HISTÓRICO' size={17} weight="500" updateState={this.updateState} />

       </ScrollableTabView>
     );

 }
```

Nessa pegada, toda vida que for chamado o updateState nos nós filhos, você atualiza o estado do nó pai a partir dos filhos.

**Em Resumo:**

Implemente métodos para alteração do estado e passe a função por props.
Lembre-se de vincular a função a instância, usando [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ou arrow-functions para alterar o estado do nó pai.

Comment: Show, vou testar daqui a pouco, obrigado pela ajuda!